# Run an android application continously for testing purposes

Tags: android

I am trying to run an android application continuously for testing purposes and noticed that the app stops after few hours. So I implemented an AlarmManager to start the activity every few hours, even with this I cannot run the app with out stopping.

I see the AlarmManger restarts the activity for few times and even it dies along with the App. Could someone suggest me how to achieve the functionality.

I really appreciate your help!
Thanks.

PS. I am testing the phone functionality using android like: cameraTest, ModemTest(playing audio, video files), Making Call, Bluetooth etc.

Comment: what kind of test app. Is it a background application?
You can use Services.

Comment: No it is not a background application, and this app is to mimic all end user activities and test the phone: browse web pages, check data connections, load youtube, make a call, send SMS etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Service that restarts the app every x minutes or something. From the docs:

"A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use. "

More [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Comment: I have used " AlarmManager which I assume is a system service". I need to restart the activity even if it is Garbage collected by Android or task killed. I had written my testing in activity as I was not sure if I can open the camera from a service and take pictures, or make a call from service.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Service with a thread continously monitoring your application status(whether running or not) and it can launch a broadcast message to your application in case it is not running.

Comment: Thanks but I have extras that I need to restart the App. Now I am passing the extras to AlarmManager and when restarting I am using those extras in the intent to restart. If I use the broadcast message to my activity how can I restore the extras? Also can I restart the activity from the service if so how do I do that with extras?

Comment: while broadcasting you can pass your bundle with the intent

Comment: Thank you! Is using a service more reliable than using an AlarmManager in this situation? Right now I can restart the App from AlarmManager but android is killing my apps along with the Alaram's indefinitely. So if I use a service, would Android not kill my service? Sorry but trying to understand how this service is different from the AlarmManager(The System Service created by android).